# A Simple Connect Wall?

Tags: word, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be partitioned into 4 groups.
Additionally, the four groups may be connected to give a hint at a *fictional character*.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BUDGE | ROLL | BOW | BOSS |
| DIE | GRAVE | APSE | CRYPT |
| PRESS | FISH | PLANE | JOY |
| BRACE | EVEN | BARK | COME |

**Can you identify the four groups?**
**What is the fictional character that links the groups together?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The wall can be resolved as follows:

> **Group 1: Add EL**
>  EL**apse**, EL**fish**, EL**bow**, EL**even**
>
>  **Group 2: Add EM**
>  EM**brace**, EM**bark**, EM**boss**, EM**press**
>
>  **Group 3: Add EN**
>  EN**crypt**, EN**joy**, EN**roll**, EN**grave**
>
>  **Group 4: Add TARY**
>  **Budge**TARY, [**Come**TARY](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cometary), **Die**TARY, **Plane**TARY

Which fictional character links these?

> **[Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes)**! Why? Well, it's [**EL-EM-EN-TARY**, my dear Watson](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2016/07/14/watson/)! (Appropriate for the title too, since 'elementary' and 'simple' are synonyms...)

Comment: +1 Drat, beat me to it :D

Comment: Ha, sorry @Sciborg - this one struck me square in the face for some reason and I was lucky to see it just 2 minutes after posting! :)

Comment: You keep answering the only questions I can solve on here 
before me loll!

Comment: Oh no! Could it possibly be ... that you are _not_ the @Smartest1here after all?

Comment: I think my name is to be taken with a pinch of salt.